# ASP.NET - Trying to run API along side a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

here's my current issue:

I have the following structure:

Solution1
_Folder1
_Folder2
_CSProj1
_CSProj2
**_WebSite**

Solution2
_Folder 
_APIProj

I've developed a simple API project and wish to integrate it in a asp.net solution (Solution1). I've been able to import the "apiproj" from "Solution2" and it works as desired, however the issue is that it is not the startup project, as the Website one is the main project and should be the the starup one. However, the website needs the apiproj to run at the same time.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue preferably without using the "multiple startup projects"

some guidance and/or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: You can tell Visual Studio to start both projects. Right click on the solution item and choose Properties then choose Startup Project and select Multiple Startup Projects. Set the Action to Start and order the projects

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple projects at the same time within the same solution by:

1. Right click the Solution
2. Set startup projects...
3. Change the option to "Multiple startup projects"
4. Set the Action against the projects you want to both run, to "Start"

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what we pretend as it creates a dependency, and we wish to run the project seamlessly